# Chained Selects Plugin, works but not for all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, chained

I'm working on one offline project to display some cars for a car dealership company and i'm using among others the Chained Selects Plugin (jQuery+Zepto) from [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained). Some other includes on my header are simple_html_dom and one menu.

I'm very happy the way it works, but we've got a big list of 2nd level dropdowns and i think it hangs somewhere..

Here are my files :

includes/header.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
set_time_limit(0); 
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/simple_html_dom.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1253" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function disableSelection(target){
if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
    target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
    target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
else //All other route (ie: Opera)
    target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
target.style.cursor = "default"
}

//Sample usages
//disableSelection(document.body) //Disable text selection on entire body
//disableSelection(document.getElementById("mydiv")) //Disable text selection on element with id="mydiv"

</script>
<style>
.mattblacktabs{
overflow: hidden;
width:450px;
background:#414141;
}
.mattblacktabs ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: bold 12px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
}
.mattblacktabs li{
display: inline;
margin: 0;
}
.mattblacktabs li a{
float: left;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 8px; /*padding inside each tab*/
border-right: 1px solid white; /*right divider between tabs*/
color: white;
background: #414141; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
}
.mattblacktabs li a:visited{
color: white;
}

.attblacktabs li a:hover, .mattblacktabs li.selected a{
background: black; /*background of tabs for hover state, plus tab with "selected" class assigned to its LI */
}

.docked{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla duration version*/
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera duration version*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*Safari shadow version*/
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*Mozilla shadow version*/
box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*CSS3 shadow version*/
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:54007/assets/jqueryslidemenu.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
html .jqueryslidemenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/
</style>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54007/assets/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54007/assets/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54007/assets/zepto-1.0.1.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54007/assets/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54007/assets/zepto-selector.js"></script>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;">

<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
<!-- <ul>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul> -->
<ul>
<li><a href="http://localhost:54007/index.php">&Alpha;&rho;&chi;&iota;&kappa;ή</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:54007/samples/index.php">Samples</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 1</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 3.1.1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>">Refresh</a></li>
<li><iframe src="/includes/none.php" align="right" height="30" width="300" name="noticeframe" scrolling="no" style="right:auto" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"> <!-- Nothing to show without the iFrame --> </iframe></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

my midle "test3.php"

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/header.php"); ?>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="cattest" target="_self">
<table width="850" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px">
  <tr>
    <td width="282"><label for="category">Κατηγορία</label><br>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="">Όλα</option>
        <option value="18">4Χ4/Τζιπ/SUV</option>
        <option value="14">Αγροτικό/Pickup</option>
        <option value="485">Αγωνιστικό</option>
        <option value="12">Κάμπριο/Roadster</option>
        <option value="11">Κομπάκτ</option>
        <option value="15">Κουπέ-σπόρ</option>
        <option value="10">Κόμπι/Kάραβαν/Van</option>
        <option value="13">Λιμουζίνα/Sedan</option>
        <option value="7">Τρέιλερ</option>
        <option value="16">Αλλο</option>
    </select></td>
    <td width="282">1-2</td>
    <td width="282"><span><?php //<input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Καθαρισμός"/>&nbsp; ?> <input type="submit" value="Έυρεση"/></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">Μάρκα<br>
                <select name="make" id="make">
                   <option value="">--</option>
                   <option value="3831">Acura</option>
                   <option value="67">Aixam</option>
                   <option value="1">Alfa Romeo</option>
                   <option value="2">Alpina</option>
                   <option value="5070">Ariel</option>
                   <option value="638">Asia Motors</option>
                   <option value="3">Aston Martin</option>
                   <option value="4">Audi</option>
                   <option value="639">Austin Healey</option>
                   <option value="5">Austin Morris</option>
                   <option value="54">Austin Rover</option>
                   <option value="3900">Autobianchi</option>
                   <option value="7">Bentley</option>
                   <option value="298">Bmw</option>
                   <option value="640">Brilliance</option>
                   <option value="641">Bugatti</option>
                   <option value="8">Buick</option>
                   <option value="9">Cadillac</option>
                   <option value="642">Caterham</option>
                   <option value="643">Chery</option>
                   <option value="10">Chevrolet</option>
                   <option value="5348">China-Motors</option>
                   <option value="11">Chrysler</option>
                   <option value="105">Citroen</option>
                   <option value="5674">Club Car</option>
                   <option value="13">Cobra</option>
                   <option value="644">Corvette</option>
                   <option value="645">Dacia</option>
                   <option value="109">Daewoo</option>
                   <option value="15">Daihatsu</option>
                   <option value="16">DeTomaso</option>
                   <option value="17">Dodge</option>
                   <option value="18">Ferrari</option>
                   <option value="124">Fiat</option>
                   <option value="126">Ford</option>
                   <option value="21">Gmc</option>
                   <option value="22">Honda</option>
                   <option value="23">Hummer</option>
                   <option value="153">Hyundai</option>
                   <option value="646">Infiniti</option>
                   <option value="25">Innocenti</option>
                   <option value="155">Isuzu</option>
                   <option value="28">Jaguar</option>
                   <option value="27">Jeep</option>
                   <option value="647">Jiangling</option>
                   <option value="288">KTM</option>
                   <option value="165">Kia</option>
                   <option value="30">Lada</option>
                   <option value="176">Lamborghini</option>
                   <option value="32">Lancia</option>
                   <option value="33">Land Rover</option>
                   <option value="3828">Landwind</option>
                   <option value="34">Lexus</option>
                   <option value="3872">Lifan</option>
                   <option value="186">Ligier</option>
                   <option value="36">Lincoln</option>
                   <option value="37">Lotus</option>
                   <option value="38">Mahindra</option>
                   <option value="39">Maserati</option>
                   <option value="648">Maybach</option>
                   <option value="192">Mazda</option>
                   <option value="196">Mercedes-Benz</option>
                   <option value="42">Mg</option>
                   <option value="43">Mini</option>
                   <option value="198">Mitsubishi</option>
                   <option value="5367">Moretti</option>
                   <option value="45">Morgan</option>
                   <option value="5044">Neptun</option>
                   <option value="205">Nissan</option>
                   <option value="649">Nsu</option>
                   <option value="208">Opel</option>
                   <option value="5366">Panther</option>
                   <option value="213">Peugeot</option>
                   <option value="48">Plymouth</option>
                   <option value="49">Pontiac</option>
                   <option value="214">Porsche</option>
                   <option value="51">Proton</option>
                   <option value="221">Renault</option>
                   <option value="53">Rolls Royce</option>
                   <option value="6">Rover</option>
                   <option value="55">Saab</option>
                   <option value="650">Santana</option>
                   <option value="232">Seat</option>
                   <option value="56">Skoda</option>
                   <option value="57">Smart</option>
                   <option value="58">SsangYong</option>
                   <option value="59">Subaru</option>
                   <option value="242">Suzuki</option>
                   <option value="65">TVR</option>
                   <option value="61">Talbot</option>
                   <option value="3830">Tata</option>
                   <option value="5565">Tazzari</option>
                   <option value="248">Toyota</option>
                   <option value="63">Trabant</option>
                   <option value="64">Triumph</option>
                   <option value="651">Uaz</option>
                   <option value="70">Ueec</option>
                   <option value="66">Vauxhall</option>
                   <option value="251">Volkswagen</option>
                   <option value="254">Volvo</option>
                   <option value="69">Wartburg</option>
                   <option value="5705">Westfield</option>
                   <option value="652">Wiesmann</option>
                   <option value="5413">Zotye</option>
                   <option value="0">Αλλο</option>
                </select></td>
    <td width="282">Τύπος<br>
                <select name="model" id="model">
                    <option value="">Όλα</option>
                <!-- Acura 3831 -->
                    <option value="1061" class="3831">MDX</option>
                    <option value="1062" class="3831">NSX</option>
                    <option value="1063" class="3831">RL</option>
                    <option value="1064" class="3831">RSX</option>
                    <option value="1065" class="3831">TL</option>
                    <option value="1066" class="3831">TSX</option>
                <!-- Aixam 67 -->
                <!--    <option value="" class="67">Όλα</option> -->
                <!-- Alfa Romeo 1 -->
                    <option value="1" class="1">Alfa 33</option>
                    <option value="2" class="1">Alfa 75</option>
                    <option value="3" class="1">Alfa 90</option>
                    <option value="4" class="1">Alfa 145</option>
                    <option value="5" class="1">Alfa 146</option>
                    <option value="6" class="1">Alfa 147</option>
                    <option value="7" class="1">Alfa 155</option>
                    <option value="8" class="1">Alfa 156</option>
                    <option value="9" class="1">Alfa 159</option>
                    <option value="10" class="1">Alfa 164</option>
                    <option value="11" class="1">Alfa 166</option>
                    <option value="12" class="1">Alfasud</option>
                    <option value="13" class="1">Alfetta</option>
                    <option value="14" class="1">Breta</option>
                    <option value="15" class="1">CrossWagon</option>
                    <option value="16" class="1">GTV</option>
                    <option value="17" class="1">GT</option>
                    <option value="18" class="1">Giulia</option>
                    <option value="19" class="1">Giulietta</option>
                    <option value="1334" class="1">Mito</option>
                    <option value="20" class="1">RZ/SZ</option>
                    <option value="21" class="1">Spider</option>
                    <option value="22" class="1">SportWagon</option>
                    <option value="23" class="1">Sprint</option>
                <!-- Alpina 2 -->
                    <option value="568" class="2">B3</option>
                    <option value="569" class="2">B5</option>
                    <option value="570" class="2">B6</option>
                    <option value="571" class="2">B7</option>
                    <option value="572" class="2">B8</option>
                    <option value="573" class="2">B10</option>
                    <option value="574" class="2">B12</option>
                    <option value="576" class="2">D3</option>
                    <option value="575" class="2">D 10</option>
                    <option value="577" class="2">Roadster S</option>
                <!-- Ariel 5070 -->
                    <option value="1336" class="5070">Atom</option>
                <!-- Asia Motors 638 -->
                    <option value="1236" class="638">Rocsta</option>
                <!-- Aston Martin 3 -->
                    <option value="979" class="3">AR1</option>
                    <option value="981" class="3">DB7</option>
                    <option value="982" class="3">DB9</option>
                    <option value="980" class="3">DB</option>
                    <option value="983" class="3">Lagonda</option>
                    <option value="985" class="3">V8 Vantage</option>
                    <option value="984" class="3">V8</option>
                    <option value="986" class="3">V12 Vanquish</option>
                    <option value="987" class="3">Vanguish</option>
                    <option value="988" class="3">Vantage</option>
                    <option value="989" class="3">Virage</option>
                    <option value="990" class="3">Volante</option>
                <!-- Audi 4 -->
                    <option value="1087" class="4">80</option>
                    <option value="1088" class="4">90</option>
                    <option value="1089" class="4">100</option>
                    <option value="1090" class="4">200</option>
                    <option value="3134" class="4">A1</option>
                    <option value="1091" class="4">A2</option>
                    <option value="1092" class="4">A3</option>
                    <option value="1093" class="4">A4</option>
                    <option value="1297" class="4">A5</option>
                    <option value="1094" class="4">A6</option>
                    <option value="3221" class="4">A7</option>
                    <option value="1095" class="4">A8</option>
                    <option value="1096" class="4">Allroad</option>
                    <option value="1097" class="4">Cabriolet</option>
                    <option value="1098" class="4">Coupe</option>
                    <option value="3205" class="4">Q3</option>
                    <option value="1303" class="4">Q5</option>
                    <option value="1099" class="4">Q7</option>
                    <option value="1100" class="4">Quattro</option>
                    <option value="1304" class="4">R8</option>
                    <option value="1101" class="4">RS2</option>
                    <option value="1102" class="4">RS4</option>
                    <option value="1103" class="4">RS6</option>
                    <option value="1104" class="4">S2</option>
                    <option value="1105" class="4">S3</option>
                    <option value="1106" class="4">S4</option>
                    <option value="1315" class="4">S5</option>
                    <option value="1107" class="4">S6</option>
                    <option value="1108" class="4">S8</option>
                    <option value="1109" class="4">TT</option>
                    <option value="1110" class="4">V8</option>
                <!-- Austin Healey 639 -->
                <!--    <option value="" class="639">Όλα</option> -->
                <!-- Austin Morris 5 -->
                <!--    <option value="" class="5">Όλα</option> -->
                <!-- Austin Rover 54 -->
                <!--    <option value="" class="54">Όλα</option> -->
                <!-- Autobianchi 3900 -->
                <!--    <option value="" class="3900">Όλα</option> -->
                <!-- Bentley 7 -->
                    <option value="1263" class="7">Arnage</option>
                    <option value="1264" class="7">Azure</option>
                    <option value="1265" class="7">Brooklands</option>
                    <option value="1266" class="7">Continental</option>
                    <option value="1267" class="7">Eight</option>
                    <option value="1268" class="7">Mulsanne</option>
                    <option value="1270" class="7">Turbo RT</option>
                    <option value="1269" class="7">Turbo R</option>
                    <option value="1271" class="7">Turbo S</option>
                <!-- BMW 238 -->
                    <option value="3238" class="238">114</option>
                    <option value="924" class="238">116</option>
                    <option value="925" class="238">118</option>
                    <option value="926" class="238">120</option>
                    <option value="1329" class="238">125</option>
                    <option value="927" class="238">130</option>
                    <option value="1330" class="238">135</option>
                    <option value="928" class="238">315</option>
                    <option value="929" class="238">316</option>
                    <option value="930" class="238">318</option>
                    <option value="931" class="238">320</option>
                    <option value="932" class="238">323</option>
                    <option value="933" class="238">324</option>
                    <option value="934" class="238">325</option>
                    <option value="935" class="238">328</option>
                    <option value="936" class="238">330</option>
                    <option value="937" class="238">335</option>
                    <option value="3281" class="238">ActiveHybrin 3</option>
                </select>
    </td>
    <td width="282">2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">Τιμή από<br>
    <select name="price-from" id="price-from">
                    <option value="">Όλα</option>
                    <option value="&gt;0">0 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;50">50 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;100">100 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;200">200 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;300">300 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;400">400 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;500">500 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;1000">1000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;1500">1500 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;2000">2000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;3000">3000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;4000">4000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;5000">5000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;6000">6000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;7000">7000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;8000">8000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;9000">9000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;10000">10000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;11000">11000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;12000">12000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;13000">13000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;14000">14000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;15000">15000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;17500">17500 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;20000">20000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;22500">22500 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;25000">25000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;27500">27500 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;30000">30000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;35000">35000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;40000">40000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;45000">45000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;50000">50000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;55000">55000 €</option>
                    <option value="&gt;60000">60000 €</option>
                </select></td>
    <td width="282">3-2</td>
    <td width="282">3-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">4-1</td>
    <td width="282">4-2</td>
    <td width="282">4-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">5-1</td>
    <td width="282">5-2</td>
    <td width="282">5-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">6-1</td>
    <td width="282">6-2</td>
    <td width="282">6-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">7-1</td>
    <td width="282">7-2</td>
    <td width="282">7-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">8-1</td>
    <td width="282">8-2</td>
    <td width="282">8-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">9-1</td>
    <td width="282">9-2</td>
    <td width="282">9-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">10-1</td>
    <td width="282">10-2</td>
    <td width="282">10-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">11-1</td>
    <td width="282">11-2</td>
    <td width="282">11-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="282">12-1</td>
    <td width="282">12-2</td>
    <td width="282">12-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="windows-1253">
    /* For jquery.chained.js (jquery.chained.min.js) */
    $("#model").chained("#make");
    $("#make").chained("#3831");
    $("#make").chained("#67");
    $("#make").chained("#1");
    $("#make").chained("#2");
    $("#make").chained("#1336");
    $("#make").chained("#1236");
    $("#make").chained("#3");
    $("#make").chained("#4");
    $("#make").chained("#639");
    $("#make").chained("#5");
    $("#make").chained("#54");
    $("#make").chained("#3900");
    $("#make").chained("#7");
    $("#make").chained("#238");
  </script>
<?php 
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/footer.php"); 
?>
```

includes/footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
disableSelection(document.body) //disable text selection on entire body of page
</script>
</body></html>
```

Can't seem to understand why it works until Bentley, but when i select BMW it doesn't display the 2nd dropdown.

Maybe i've missed something, can't seem to see what.

Help is greatly needed and will be appreciated.

Thank you very much, in advance!

Comment: the code above is used inside a portable web server as application using PHPDesktop (https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) and 
i've got no action ("") cause i need the values on the url instead of submiting them somewhere (db etc), another script fetches the values for use!

Comment: Try launching Developer Tools in phpdesktop to see if there are any javascript errors on a page. Devtools is available through mouse context menu.

Comment: i'll do that and report back here.. thank you @CzarekTomczak

Comment: sorry i was late to answer here, well it was a mistake of mine, did formating wrong, got it work now. (i was channing wrong stuff :S)